# Manual duplex (two-sided) printing of a PDF doc?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-reader

I am using Adobe Reader 9.

I have a [printer](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?product=3919448&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&cc=us) that does NOT support duplex printing.

I need to print a 350 pages book, and I don't have another printer.

**How do I manually print it double sided?**

It's a text book with some diagrams; will it finish out the ink? what consideration should I take before printing? Maybe there is a company I can order PDF prints from?

**UPDATE**
After realizing that printing is not the right option for me, please read [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13003/order-printed-pdf-docs-online) question.

Comment: Unfortunately, they decided that your other question was OT and closed it. Commercial services will typically be more touchy about copyright. If the book is your own, then you can use a number of services ranging from your local copy center (Kinkos in the US even has a printer driver that lets you File|Print and get a box in the mail a few days later) to self-publish vendors like Lulu which can print and bind as a book. If you don't own copyright, you may run into terms of use issues.

Comment: The book has no copyrights. besides my question wasn't about copyrights. Thanks for the names anyhow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you choose `File > Print...`, there's a button labeled `Subset: All pages in range`. You can click on that button and `Odd Pages Only` or `Even Pages Only`. Do one of those and print the document. Flip the pages over and put them back into the input tray and print the document again after choosing the other. Practice on a short document first to make sure you know which way the pages need to be collated after the first print.

How many pages you're able to print depends on whether you have the extra large or regular black cartridge, whether you print in color or set the output to black only, what print quality you choose (draft, etc.) and how much you've used the cartridge(s) before. The density of text and the amount of graphics will have a lot to do with it as well. HP rates the regular black cartridge for that printer at 200 pages and the extra large black cartridge at 700 pages.

Comment: I guess I won't printed, it's indeed a new cartridge, but I only got one. please refer to [my further question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13003/order-printed-pdf-docs-online).

Answer (score 5):

In the print dialog for Adobe Reader, under the Print Range section, there is a "Subset" dropdown/combobox. Select either "Odd Pages Only" or "Even pages Only" and print your whole document. When that has printed, load the printed sheets into the paper tray, making sure that it will print on the blank side of the paper, and print again, but this time select the other subset option.

This may be a little tricky at first, you will have to visualise how your printer prints and outputs the pages, face up/down, in order or reversed. You can probably save yourself the hassle of re-ordering pages manually by using the "Reverse pages" checkbox.

I printed a 1200 page document using this method, after a little testing of the procedure, it worked great.

According to your printer specs, your black cartridge will only print 200 pages, so you will need at least 2 cartridges.

Comment: I guess I won't printed, it's indeed a new cartridge, but I only got one. please refer to [my further question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13003/order-printed-pdf-docs-online).

Comment: +1 for reverse pages. I do: print even pages, reverse pages, flip papers into paper tray, then print odd pages, no reverse pages.